# Setting item in session storage when navigating to another page in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to save a bool true when onClick when navigating to another page in React.

When the IconButton is pressed, the user navigates to /app/new and bookRide objects is being stringified and saved with status: true. When the user navigates back to the BookRide component, this status is still true.

```
class BookRide extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        let bookRide= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('bookRide'));
this.state = {
bookRide: bookRide? bookRide: { status: false },
}
this.handleBookRide= this.handleBookRide.bind(this);
}

    handleBookRide= () => {
        this.setState(() => ({
            bookRide: {
                ...this.state.bookRide,
                status: true,
            }
        }), function callback() {
            const { bookRide} = this.state;
            sessionStorage.setItem('bookRide', JSON.stringify(bookRide));
        })
    }

render() {
return (
             <IconButton
                                    component={Link}
                                    to={{
                                        pathname: `/app/new`,
                                    }}
                                    onClick={this.handleBookRide}
                                </IconButton>
)}

}
```

Currently, bookRide object is not being saved in sessionStorage at all.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example for us to be able to help you

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings: this is a fully reproducible example? Are you talking about adding imports?

Answer (score 0):

the IconButton functionality to Link was causing an issue. Re-wrote to this:

```
class BookRide extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        let bookRide= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('bookRide'));
this.state = {
bookRide: bookRide? bookRide: { status: false },
}
this.handleBookRide= this.handleBookRide.bind(this);
}

    handleBookRide= () => {
        this.setState(() => ({
            bookRide: {
                ...this.state.bookRide,
                status: true,
            }
        }), function callback() {
            const { bookRide} = this.state;
            sessionStorage.setItem('bookRide', JSON.stringify(bookRide));
this.props.history.push (`/app/riders/new`);
        })
    }

render() {
return (
             <IconButton
                                    onClick={this.handleBookRide}
                                </IconButton>
)}

}
```